# Product Einstein Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In the book Einstein Manifolds by Besse it states the product of two Riemannian manifolds which are Einstein with the same constant $\lambda$ is an Einstein manifold with the same constant $\lambda$. Can someone provide a proof of this? Also what happens if the two manifolds are Einstein with different constants. Is the resulting product manifold still Einstein?

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how the curvature tensor (and, hence, Ricci tensor) behaves under the direct product?

Comment: If $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$ are Einstein with different Einstein constants, then $(M_1\times M_2, g_1 + g_2)$ is not Einstein as the answer below illustrates. However, $M_1\times M_2$ can still admit Einstein metrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to all your questions can be derived from the fact that if $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are (pseudo)Riemannian manifolds, and $(P,k)$ is their product, then the metric tensor satisfies
$$ k = \begin{pmatrix} g & 0\\ 0 & h\end{pmatrix} $$
and the Ricci curvature satisfies
$$ \mathrm{Ric}[k] = \begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{Ric}[g] & 0 \\ 0 & \mathrm{Ric}[h] \end{pmatrix}. $$

The formula for the metric tensor is the definition of the product manifold. The formula for Ricci curvature can be found via a direct computation which is done it most textbooks in Riemannian geometry.